# How can we convert below code without lambda expressions and streams?

Tags: java, spring-boot, lambda, foreach, response-entity

How to convert below code to for each loop without using lambda expressions and streams in Java?

```
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
        HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    List<String> validationList = ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().stream()
            .map(fieldError -> fieldError.getDefaultMessage()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(validationList, status);
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Always use a programming language tag on your questions, it will ensure they get seen by the maximum number of people

Comment: `for (FieldError fieldError : ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()) validationList.add(fieldError.getDefaultMessage());`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
                HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    List<String> validationList = ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().stream()
            .map(fieldError -> fieldError.getDefaultMessage()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(validationList, status);
}
```

It will be converted to below code:

```
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
                HttpHeaders headers, 
                HttpStatus status, 
                WebRequest request) {
    List<String> validationList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<FieldError> validationErrorList = ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors();
    for(FieldError fieldError: validationErrorList) {
        validationList.add(fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(validationList, status);
}
```